# Problema con math.min() en array java script

Tags: javascript, array, funciones

tengo que hacer una función que sume los dos números mas chicos de una array, pero tengo problemas con el math.min() a continuación inserto el código así me explico mejor

```
  function minSum(array) {
let min = Math.min(...array);
let i = array[Math.min(...array)]
let removido = array.splice(i, 1)
let min2 = Math.min(...array);
let res = min + min2
return res;
```

el problema es que cuando la pruebo con este array: minSum([5, 2, 6, 7]); a la variable i me la declara como 6 cuando la tendría que declarar como 2 ya que es el numero mas chico del array.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de @Lobos es correcta, otra forma de encontrar los dos números pequeños sería ordenandolos primero, te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
function minSum(arr){
  const [min0, min1] = arr.sort((a, b) => a-b).slice(0,2);
  return min0+min1;
}

const result = minSum([3,3,5,654,6,7,1]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay un error en la búsqueda del índice del número más pequeño.

```js
let array = [5, 2, 6, 7];
// se encuentra el min del arreglo, ese es 2.
let min = Math.min(...array);
// se obtiene el índice donde se encuentra el número más
// pequeño, ese es 1.
let i = array.indexOf(min)

// si se hace let i = array[Math.min(array)]
// eso equivale a array[2] y array[2] == 6


let removido = array.splice(i, 1)
let min2 = Math.min(...array);
let res = min + min2;

console.log(res);
```